# how do i delete the numbers at the begining of a each line file?

Tags: bash, shell

If a file contains numbers like at the begining of each line like :

```
1 hello wolrd!
2 gjdshjkjkgn*90&
3 {)/>husdfghjhs
```

and so on

how do i delete the line numbers from the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]*//'
```

Comment: OP did not want to remove spaces

Answer (score 1):

`perl -npe 's/^[0-9]+//'` am sure you could also do it using sed or awk as well.

Answer (score 1):

cnicutar's answer is better, and certainly more maintainable for large amounts of data, but I think it might be worth pointing out that some text editors provide vertical selection (eg. by holding down ALT or CTL, for example, while selecting text with the mouse).  If you have such a text editor open already on a file, it could be faster than running something from the commandline.

Still, cnicutar's answer is better, particularly with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

Cut is designed for exactly this
`cut -d ' ' -f 2-`

Comment: This would also remove the space after the number (as there would be no more first column to separate from the second).

Comment: I don't see a requirement to keep that space